# Oops, you said Boruch Atta Hashem Elokeinu in error

Tags: halacha, mistakes

When one says "Boruch Atta Hashem" in error he can say "Lamdeini Chukecha (לַמְּדֵנִי חֻקֶּיךָ)" and this way he did not say Hashem's name in vain since he has then said a complete verse (Psalms 119:12). Is there anything one can do if he said "Boruch Atta Hashem Elokeinu" in error other than saying "Boruch Shaim Kevod Malchuso Lolam Vaed"? (Source please.)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/boruch-shem-kevod-malchuso-lolam-voed-after-saying-hashems-name-in-error

Comment: Perhaps whatever source says to say "לַמְּדֵנִי חֻקֶּיךָ" also advises something for the case in your question. Do you know what that source is? (I don't.)

Comment: Not posting this as an answer (because I'm not sure), but couldn't you say "Baruch Hu, u'Varuch shemo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the verse (Deuteronomy 5:2):

> יהוה אֱלֹהֵינוּ כָּרַת עִמָּנוּ בְּרִית בְּחֹרֵב

Comment: a source would be appreciated as although I have heard to do as your answer, I have been unable to find any source that suggests this.

Comment: I would accept your answer if a source was added in.

Comment: http://www.shtaygen.net/leaflet/Omka/72/174.pdf

Comment: piskei teshuvot oc 206 ft #109

Answer (score 3):

If you just said "Boruch Atta Hashem Elokei-" you can finish it with the end of the [passuk](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%98_%D7%99) (and you can say "baruch shem..." after that):

> ברוך אתה ה' אלוהי ישראל אבינו, מעולם, ועד-עולם

If you already said Elokeinu, you may be stuck, since there's no passuk that has all those words together. I'm not sure if DoubleAA's suggestion would work since you used "ברוך אתה" as part of the phrase, so I think at that point you should just say "Boruch Shem".

Source Update: [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 6:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%95#.28.D7.93.29).

Comment: This is not saying a complete pasuk. Why would it be better than any other praiseworthy statement?

Comment: Who says you need to say a complete passuk? One can quote any part of a passuk. I'm aware some have a chumra to say a whole passuk, but that shouldn't affect what you do when stuck.

Comment: Who says you have to say anything related to a pasuk? Just say something praiseworthy.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I added a source. I'm not sure why it needs to be a pasuk, but that is the custom.

Comment: The kitzur says to say Baruch Shem too in this case.

Comment: edited. not sure why necessary, but maybe he doesn't like half-pesukim either.

Comment: Rav Moshe Levi writes in Birkat Hashem that even if you said Elokenu you can still finish that Pasuk (his source is Haye Adam Kelal 5) however he writes that even if you said that Pasuk you should still say Baruch Kevod Shem Malchuto because it's not a full Pasuk.