# Saying Baruch Sheim out loud on a bracha

Tags: halacha, blessing, loud-quiet

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73227/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93-after-a-bracha-with-a-false-statement).

We know (Pesachim 56b) that Baruch Sheim, at least according to one explanation, is a tefillah Moshe heard from the Malachim. Thus, we only say it out loud when we're on the level of Malachim.

Yet, we (by that I mean the minhag in my community* - not sure whether this is true everywhere) say Baruch Sheim out loud after messing up a bracha beyond the point of "lamdeini chukecha." If we're not on the level of malachim, why should we be allowed to do so?

*Note that my community is primarily formed of talmidim of R' Weinberg of Ner Yisrael fame.

Comment: of interest: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/why-do-we-say-boruch-shem-loudly-on-yom-kippur

Comment: IIRC RJBS would say BSKMLV to himself on Yom Kippur if saying Shema alone. Seemingly he felt the whole outloud/quiet business is just part of Tefillah beTzibbur, so there'd be no preference in your case.