# Why do we say "Boruch Shem..." loudly on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, minhag, yom-kippur, shema, loud-quiet

As discussed in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8063/603), there are two reasons generally given why we say "Boruch Shem K'Vod..." quietly when saying Shema:

- The Talmud ([Pesachim 56a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=56&format=pdf)) says that Yaakov Avinu said it in response to his children's declaration of "Shema Yisroel", but Moshe does not say it in [Devarim 6:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9970#showrashi=true&v=4). The Rabbis weren't sure whether they should say it (like Yaakov) or not say it (like Moshe) so the concluded that it should be said quietly.
- Midrash ([Devarim Rabbah 2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba5/2.htm):36) says that Moshe stole the praise from the angels. The Midrash continues to explain by way of parable that during the year we hide the fact that we're saying it. On Yom Kippur however, when we are as "clean as angels" we say it out loud.

According to the reason given in the Talmud, why do we say "Boruch Shem..." out loud on Yom Kippur? It doesn't seem like Yom Kippur should make a difference. (as opposed to the midrash reason, because on yom-kippur we are similar to angel's)

Comment: Note that in the Talmud R' Avahu says that there were times and places where "Boruch Shem..." was said aloud during the regular year.

Comment: see http://www.shemayisrael.com/dafyomi2/berachos/insites/br-dt-03.htm, which may have some connection to a possible answer (The idea that "Yehei Shmei Rabbah" is a translation of "Boruch Shem" and that "Yehei Shmei" should be said with all one's strength). I'm not sure what the answer would be though, other than that seems to indicate that the default should be to say Boruch Shem out loud, and only because Moshe didn't say it do we say it quietly. Perhaps this somehow doesn't apply on Y"K. Perhaps Yaakov trunps Moshe on Y"K (Rachamim over Emet?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following explanation of the Abarbenel who unites the explanation of the Talmud with the explanation of the Midrash and resolves your question. He explains that "baruch shem..." refers to a deeper understanding of the unity of God. This is why it is reserved for angels and Moshe did not want to say it in the Torah. However, Yaackov, speaking privately to his sons, thought they were worthy of being taught it, and therefore he taught it to them. For this reason all year we whisper it, but on Yom Kippur, when we are spiritualy on a higher level, we say it out loud.

[אברבנאל דברים פרק ו:ד](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40214&pgnum=30)

> ואתה דע שמלבד שני הראיות האלה שיאמר עליהם שם האחד יש עוד בחינה שלישית באחדות והיא ששם האחד יאמר על הכלל והשלמות כי אחד ושלם יאמרו בהרדפה כמו שבא בספר מה שאחר הטבע. ולכן נאמר והיה המשכן אחד ר"ל שלם וכולל כל מה שצריך. ומזה הצד ג"כ שהש"י אחד ר"ל שהוא שלם וכולל כל השלמיות. ומהבחינה הזאת היה האחדות והמלכות דבר אחד בעצמו כי המלכות איננו רק יחיד מעלה ושולטנות שכל השררות והמעלות נכללות בו. וכן נאמר והיה ה' למלך על כל הארץ ביום ההוא יהיה ה' אחד ושמו אחד כי כשיהיה השם שלם והכסא שלם אז יגמר המלכות גם האחדות שהם דבר אחד בעצמו ומפני זה תקנו בתפלת ראש השנה שיהיה פסוק ה' אלהינו ה' אחד עולה מהמלכיות וממנינם ולהיות מין שלישי מהאחדות היינו אנחנו קהל המיחדים עונים אחר פסוק היחוד ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד לפי שהאחדות מורה על המלכות באמת. האמנם לפי שהשני מינים הראשונים שזכרתי מהיחוד האלהי משלילת ההרכבה והשניות הם המפורסמים ומושגים בהבנתם אצל ההמון. והמובן השלישי מהשלמות והמלכות הוא היותר נשגב ונסתר ומופלא והוא ענין מסור אל השכל המופשט. ויש לומר הסכמת האחדות והשלמות והכללות האמתי מכל צד אשר נלאו פיות חכמי הספירות האלהיים מלבאר ומפני זה אמרו רז"ל בדברים רבה ופסחים פרק מקום שנהגו (דף נו) שקלוס ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד היה מיוחד אל מלאכי השרת ושמשה רבינו ע"ה למדו מהם כי התאחדות המלכות והאחדות הוא ודאי שבח מיוחד אל השכלתם העליונה. ולזה אמרו במדרש נימריה לא אמרי' משה לא נימרי' הא אמריה יעקב אלא נימריה בחשאי. רצו בזה שמשה רבינו ע"ה כיון ללמד היחוד אל עם ישראל בכלל ולכן נסתפק בשלילת ההרכבה ובשלילת השניות כמו שהתבאר מדבריו ולא ביאר אליהם הענין השלישי מהסכמת המלכות עם האחדות. אמנם יעקב אבינו ע"ה לפי היו דבריו עם בניו החכמים והיתה מטתו שלמה כי היו כלם כמלאכי השרת כשאמרו שמע ישראל ה' אלהינו ה' אחד כשם שאין בלבך אלא אחד כך אין בלבנו אלא אחד. כמו שיש במדרש ענה ואמר ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד. כי הוסיף המין השלישי מהאחדות על דבר בניו ועל כן היתה הסכמתם ז"ל נימרי' בחשאי. רצו לומר שהשגת המדע הזה הוא מיוחד לשלמים לא לכל המון העם. האמנם ביום הכפורים שכלנו כמלאכי השרת היינו אומרים אותו בפרהסיא כי הנה קלסונו אז להש"י כקלוס מלאכי השרת בתת המלכות והשלמות העליון הכולל מתיחד עם היחוד האמתי וזה כולו מה שנכלל במדע הראשון הזה מאחדות הש"י היוצא מאותו דבור ששמעו ראשונה כמו שזכרתי:‏