# What is the throne of glory?

Tags: maseches-shabbos, standing-sitting, heaven

The gemarah in Shabbos 152b talks about souls that come from under the [throne of glory](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%90_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93). I would like to know conceptually what this is and for what purpose was it created?

Comment: @msh210 What's that tag for?

Comment: @Scimonster the question's about a chair, innit? But of course feel free to detag if you think the tag's inappropriate here. (Especially as your comment has an uptick.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Throne of Glory seems to represent Hashem's manifestation, or the manifestation of Hashem's directing the world, in the world. (I explained [elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/what-does-baruch-shem-kvod-malchuso-lolam-vaed-mean/35673#35673) that "honor" means manifestation or presence.)

Medrash Tanchuma Shoftim 9:

> אמר רבי חנינא עתיד הקב"ה להראות כבודו לכל באי עולם ולהוריד כסא באמצע הרקיע
>
> Rebbi Chanina said: In the future, Hakadosh Baruch Hu will show his Honor to all mankind and lower a Throne from Heaven...

HaKsav V'HaKaballah Shemos 17:16:

> כי יד על כס - נראה לי שהנהגת העולם התחתון על ידי השמים וחייליהם כהטבע מכונה כסא
>
> A hand on the Throne - It seems to me that the directing of the lower world by the Heavens ... is called "Throne"

Sfas Emes Pesach 5635:

> כי הכסא הוא הוראה על המלכות ואשר הממשלה שלו, לכן נאמר השמים כסאי, כי בעולם הזה אין נגלה כח מלכותו יתברך על ידי עמלק הרשע
>
> The Throne is the display of Rulership and that dominion is His.  Therefore is says "the Heavens is my Throne" because in this world the force of Hashems Rulership is not as clearly revealed due to Amalek.

Michtav M'Elyahu 3:238

> הכסא הוא צירוף כל גילויי קדוש השם שמגלים הבריות
>
> The Throne is the combination of all of the revelation of Hashem's holiness which is revealed by Creation.

The Throne is symbolic of the revelation of Hashem in the world.  I think that the souls of the righteous are carved out from under the Throne of Glory because the righteous bring the greatest revelation of Hashem and His holiness into the world.