# Proper kavanah for baruch shem kevod?

Tags: shema

What intention should one be having when reciting "baruch shem kevod malchuto le'olam vaed" in the shema?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/what-does-baruch-shem-kvod-malchuso-lolam-vaed-mean?rq=1

Comment: As with anything you are saying, you should focus on the meaning of the words, no?

Comment: My understanding - One of the obligations of reciting *shema* is *Kabalat Ol malchut shamayim* - acceptance of the yoke of the Kingdom of Heaven. Within the phrase *Baruch shem kvod malchuto* we have the concept of *malchut* - kingdom. So, I think that's the focus of the concentration, here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I have a siddur with English translation. I read the translation every single day and it still doesn't make any sense to me. Same with Boreh Nefashot - but that's another story.

Comment: @Ani Then see the linked question about what it means.

Comment: I once tried to draft the main views as a proposed article for the synagogue magazine until the Rabbi showed me a book in Hebrew written only on this subject. I can't find the book through Google.

Comment: @AniYodea, how detailed an answer do you want? The intentions (כוונות) for Shema are one of the most detailed and involved that one can learn. Are you looking for a full-blown response or a general idea?

Comment: @YaacovDeane, whatever you can offer will be appreciated

Answer (score -3):

In Hebrew it means: Bless the name of the kingdom of HaShem. That is if you translate Baruch to bless.
        There is another translation in Nefesh H-Chaim. "Baruch" means by Nefesh H-Chaim, to bring the "Shefa" (abundance) of hashem to the "lower" places. that the grace of G-d will come from him down to us. (I believe that many others translate Baruch like that) 
        This translation comes from the idea that the word Baruch comes from an agricultural technique that's called "l-haBrich". This technique is to bend a branch into the ground. From this branch grows a new plant. Which means to take the "Shefa" of the father plant and to bring it down to earth and from there to create a new tree.

From Nefesh H-Chaim there is a new understanding: "to bring the "Shefa" (abundance) from the name of HaShem's kingdom to us."

Bracha and Hazlacha

Comment: This seems to be a translation or midrash on the meaning of the phrase, and not an answer to the question.