# Do we say "baruch shem kvod" in a whisper when not saying Shma?

Tags: tefilla, shema, loud-quiet

As per [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/boruch-shem-kevod-malchuso-lolam-voed-why-do-we-whisper-it) question, we whisper the statement Baruch Shem Kvod Malchuto L'olam Va'ed duirng shma (except on Yom Kippur). But what about when we say the phrase not as part of shma? Do we whisper it then?

When I put on my shel rosh, I say the phrase. Should I intentionally be lowering my voice at that moment or does the phrase only require special whispering when it is part of the shma?

Comment: The Mesoras HaRav Yom Kippur Machzor mentions that the Rav asked his father R. Moshe to ask his father R. Chaim if a person may recite 'baruch shem' out loud during the year. He responded that a person praying in private may, as it is only improper when a part of 'tefillah betzibbur'. Accordingly, it would be fine to say it out loud when alone, and I suspect, even in public as it is still not a part of public prayer in general, or the Shema-Baruch Shem prayer in particular. See the explanation given there.

Comment: @mevaqesh I saw a reference to that, but it only dealt with Baruch as part of SHma. I can see the logical leap to non-Shma based recitations, but I wonder, according to those who don't say it out loud even alone, what the answer is.

Comment: If it's any indication for me to say that the answer is - "It applies only to Shema", view the many times we say it aloud on Yom Kippur outside Shema - A piyut in Shacharit, 3 times during *Avodah* in Musaf, and 3 times at the end of *Ne'ilah*. All these places (except, perhaps for Shacharit piyut), it's said aloud.

Comment: @Danno "according to those who don't say it out loud even alone" who? (That is, have you seen any poskim who write this, or are you simply referencing the popular convention. If the latter, be aware that that convention probably was the same for the last 150 years, yet the Rav et al. still felt that in private it _could_ be recited aloud).

Comment: @mevaqesh If there is an opinion that says that you CAN say it aloud, in private, I figured that there was some established understanding that one would NOT say it aloud, in private.

Comment: @DanF but because we say those piyuttim only on Y"K we can't tell if we would have said those words quietly on any other day. Is there a piyut we say on another yom tov with the Baruch Shem line as a refrain which we whisper?

Comment: Hey @Danno. I got your question. Other than the recitation of *Baruch SHem* after putting on tefillin, I don't think that there's any other time during the year that we recite this phrase outside Shema. However, what may be worthwhile exploring are 3aspects: 1) It is said as part of Ne'ilah AND originally, Nei'lah was part of a Ta'anit tzibbur and *Baruch Shem* is said ALOUD in Yom Kippur Katan. These still make me feel that the silent treatment is only required in Shema. As you see, it is not just a Yom Kippur occurrence.

Comment: I saw quoted from the Maharsha that the reason to say it quietly is to avoid hefsek in shma. Accordingly, outside if shma, one may say it out loud.

Comment: The concept of saying 'Baruch Shem...' outside of the recital of Shema is brought by Rabbi Ganzfried in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch. It is to be said when a mistake is made in the recital of a bracha.

Comment: The concept of saying quietly is only for Shema and relates to Yaacov Avinu and his sons. Good Shabbos everyone!

Answer (score 1):

HaRav Hershel Schachter is of the opinion that it's permissible to say Baruch Shem out loud outside of the context of Keriat Shema, such as when singing Ana BeKoach during Kabbalat Shabbat. The Ben Ish Chai (Od Yosef Chai, Shanah Rishonah, Parashat Miketz 8), however, states unequivocally that one should be careful to say Baruch Shem quietly, in the context of Ana beKoach. Seemingly, he disagrees across the board.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is setup in a silent tone is because it is a phrase that is used only by angels.
 Which is reason why on the fast yom kippur alone? Because we are compared to angels (and many other custom to dress in white). So, yes I believe even when said not during the prayer of shema, it should be said silently. However on the other hand the angels only say it when we pray or at certain times so may be ok

Comment: Please respect the rest of us enough to write in somewhat proper English. This is full of obvious typos and includes no punctuation whatsoever. It's hard for us to read and understand.

Comment: when after tefilin of head we say BSMLV we are also compared to an angels?

Comment: not that i know of